# Postgresql. CREATE CAST 'character varying' to 'integer'

Tags: postgresql

I want to CREATE CAST a suitable function to convert 'character varying' to 'integer'. Can anyone suggest a function? Everything I try fails.

Comment: You should fix your SQL to not rely in implict casts. Do not rely on implict casts in your statements, never.

Comment: I agree. However I cannot I'm using a off-the-shelf piece of software.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use this:

```
CREATE CAST (varchar AS integer) WITH INOUT [AS IMPLICIT];
```

It uses the input/output functions of the data types involved.

Comment: More than 3k views/sp/queries to review&fix implicit casts... then you came with this f**** easy workaround. It'll get me so much more time. Thank you, job saver! (I'm wondering why postgres developers didn't put a parameter in postgresql.conf for this...)

Answer (score 1):

The function above works if you update your SQL to do an explicit cast.
However,  if you add 'as implicit' to the end of your "create cast" statement, Postgres will be able to automatically figure out what you are trying to do when you compare an integer with a varchar that can be converted to an integer.

Here is my updated statement that seemed to work "implicitly":

```
CREATE FUNCTION toint(varchar) 
  RETURNS integer 
  STRICT IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS 
'SELECT cast($1 as integer);';

CREATE CAST (varchar AS integer) WITH FUNCTION toint(varchar) as Implicit;
```

Comment: This function was helpful for me to cast varchar fields as a regular DB user issuing queries rather than casting the type itself.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get back the behaviour of Postgres 8.3 regarding implicit casting.

See this blog entry for examples:
http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2008/03/readding-implicit-casts-in-postgresql.html

Oh: and bug that vendor of the software to fix the broken SQL ;)

**Edit**

This should do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION toint(varchar) 
  RETURNS integer 
  STRICT IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS 
'SELECT cast($1 as integer);';

CREATE CAST (varchar AS integer) WITH FUNCTION toint(varchar);
```

Comment: Yeah. I found that but it's missing int4(varchar)

Comment: It contains a cast for integer which is the same as int4 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm being stupid but none of the functions return an integer. I expect to do CREATE CAST (varchar as integer)...

Comment: Forgive *me*! **I** was stupid. I thought you wanted the 8.3 behaviour back (int to varchar).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I have a COLUMN

> code

declared as type character varying(20) and a local variable

> l_code

declared as type int.

I solved replacing in the procedure

```
SELECT 
...
WHERE
code = l_code AND
..
```

with

```
code = cast( l_code as character varying)   AND
```