# Are there some "direct casts" for JSONB parameters?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

This is a typical [wrap function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) (overloading a non-json `foo()`  function) for use in JSONB context,

```
-- suppose FUNCTION foo(text[], numeric, boolean) returns int.

CREATE FUNCTION foo(JSONB) RETURNS int AS $f$
    SELECT foo(
        (SELECT array_agg(x) FROM jsonb_array_elements_text($1->'list') t(x) ),
        ($1->>'lim')::numeric, -- why cast JSONB number to numeric?
        ($1->>'osort')::boolean  -- idem for boolean
    );
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Is there an elegant way to cast a `JSONB` *string* array into SQL `text` array?  Why we need this ugly `numeric` and `boolean` casts if the internal representation says its datatypes?

---

EDITED after good @IgorRomanchenko discussion:

### PHILOSOPHIC NOTES

My preocupation is

> Why PostreSQL 9.5 **is losing JSONB** internal datatype information and internal (number and boolean) representations?

In nowadays the runtime engine use CPU to convert *JSONB number* to text and text to *SQL numeric*, or boolean to text them text to boolean... Ideal (optimized) is "to by-pass" JSONB internal representations, or only casts "binary to binary"  (not parse to text and cast text to binary).

PostgreSQL will be more optimized and friendly when internally using  JSONB datatype (`jsonb_typeof`)!

PS1: the `SELECT array_agg(x) FROM jsonb_array_elements_text()` example only amplifies and exposes the same problem. In this case we also need a direct `jsonb_array_to_array(x,type)` function to by-pass array bynary representation.

PS2: [CREATE CAST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4760759/287948) is not a solution to this problem, because destroys the original JSONB representations.

---

... How to do it?

Hum... Perhaps creating alternative casting types like `::numericByPass` to "bypass JSONB binary number to SQL numeric" and `::booleanByPass` "bypass JSONB boolean to SQL boolean", so, **preserving**  internal representation, **not** parsing it as a text value. Of course, if runtime check see string instead expected datatype, it triggers an error.

Looking at the example we see that the context obligates to use number and boolean, the user not need to say it to the compiler.

The SQL parser can  use this implicit "context obligation" to do by it self, in compile time, the cast to `::numericByPass`  and `::booleanByPass`, preserving JSONB internal representations. If the user is really afraid about string inputs, only in this case the user will add explicit `::numeric`  and `::boolean` castings.

Comment: Type casts are needed because types are checked at compile time. Actual information about JSON structure is available only at runtime.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko the constraints (see `foo(text[],int, boolean)` definition) imposes a compile time casting, not need runtime check... A friendly  language undertand the context. The cast `::int` also impose a parsing cost that the context not need.

Answer (score 1):

You need runtime casts and checks because an input JSON does not define any structure. You can not check that this input JSON has field `"list"` with text array in it or a field `"lim"` with an integer.

Take this example JSON:

```
{
"list":42,
"lim": [3,5],
"osort": "maybe"
}
```

Current function will throw type cast exceptions because it has runtime casts and checks. What will this function do without any runtime checks?

BTW If you really want postgres to do this for you - you can enable implicit cast from `varchar` to `int` and `boolean` as in this post: [Postgresql. CREATE CAST 'character varying' to 'integer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760759/postgresql-create-cast-character-varying-to-integer)

It is not the best idea, but it will work.

Comment: As I commented before, there are a problem (non-friendly language) because all context was declared in compile time: the language can put by it self the `::int` and `::boolean`.

Comment: @PeterKrauss See my addition to the answer on how to enable implicit casts.

Comment: Thanks all discussion and directions (!)... I will edit the question, it is a preocupation to not **lost JSONB representation** (different than JSON where all are string)... All context was declared in compile time: the language can put by it self  something as `::intByPass` and `::booleanByPass` to reuse JSONB datatypes... So if in  runtime a string arrives, it triggs an error... And,  if user not need performance and need avoid strings,  user add `::int` (only in this case!).

Answer (score 0):

You can create different operators similar to ->> that produce different output types. For example, -># could give you a number and ->| a boolean.

```
CREATE FUNCTION json_numeric(
    j json
    , e text
) RETURNS NUMERIC IMMUTABLE STRICT LANGUAGE SQL AS $$
    SELECT (j->>e)::numeric
$$;

CREATE OPERATOR -># ( PROCEDURE = json_numeric, LEFTARG = json, RIGHTARG = text );

SELECT ('{"a": 42, "b": "1"}')::json -># 'a';
 ?column? 
----------
       42
(1 row)

SELECT ('{"a": 42, "b": "1"}')::json -># 'b';
 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

If you used plpgsql you could throw an error if json_typeof() wasn't correct, but note that will be significantly slower than the SQL version (though in most usage that won't matter).